# Cannot Create an LinkedList<String, int>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, linked-list

i want to create an LinkedList of couple  that the key is a String and the value is an integer ?

Comment: Do you?  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  *What is your specific question?*

Comment: i want to have a structure <string,int> that the key is a string and the value is an integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use Object in a LinkedList., this means you cant use Java Primitives.
However, what you seem to need is a Map structure.

I recommend using java.util.HashMap, it allows you to create a Key, Value pairs.

Example:

```
    HashMap<String,Integer> a = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    a.put("one",1);
    a.put("two",2);

    System.out.println(a.get("one"));
    //prints 1
    System.out.println(a.get("two"));
    //prints 2
```

EDIT:
As per your  comment, i see you required order, use the following example then:

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> b = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();

    b.put("one",1);
    b.put("two",2);
    b.put("a",3);

    for (String key:b.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(b.get(key));    // print 1 then 2 finally 3
    }
```

Hope this is what you were asking (if so, modify your question).

Comment: I lost the order of elements when i use HashMap

Comment: In that case use a LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>

Comment: check my modification of the answer, probably is what you want.

Answer (score 8):

`LinkedList` doesn't *have* a key. It's a list of elements, *not* a key/value mapping.

If you want a `LinkedList` where each element is a pair of `Integer`/`String` values, you'll need to pick one of:

- Create a generic `Pair` class
- (Ab)use an existing generic class (e.g. `Map.Entry`)
- Create a custom class for your specific scenario

I would suggest the last option as the most sensible one - you'll be able to give it appropriate semantics and names according to the *real meaning* of the string and the integer. Heck, you'll also be able to avoid boxing the integer, as you can have:

```
public class WhateverYouCallIt {
    private final int firstValue;
    private final String secondValue;

    // Constructor, properties
}
```

Comment: hashMap is much better HashMap<String,Integer> a = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

Comment: or even better `Map<String,Integer> a = new HashMap<String,Integer>();` I prefer LinkedHashMap as it keeps the order elements are added. (so they are predictable)

Comment: i have lost the order , is there a solution

Comment: @WassimSboui: What do you mean by "much better"? Either you want a map or you don't. If you want a map which preserves order, you might want `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 3):

One error is you need `Integer` instead of `int`, but as others have pointed out `LinkedList` doesn't take Key/Value pairs.

Comment: LinkedList<String,Integer> list= new LinkedList<String,Integer>(); dosen't work

Comment: is there a strcuture that take key/value and the key is a string , value is an integer

Comment: @WassimSboui Yes a `Map` takes key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine a HashMap is what your after. As other have stated, you cannot use a primitive type such as "int" in a library storage class like LinkedList, or ArrayList, you must instead use an object such as "Integer".

HashMap hash = new HashMap();

Read this for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Use the interface e.g. `Map<String,Integer> hash = new HashMap<String,Integer>();`

Comment: I lost the order of elements when i use HashMap